# Conditional probability density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have two independent Gaussian random variables $X$ and $Z$.

Let $G = X-Z$, then $G$ is Gaussian with parameters $\mu_G= \mu_X - \mu_Z$ and $\sigma_G^2 = \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Z^2$.

I know that $Z=f(W, Y)$, where $W$ and $Y$ are both random variables and $f$ is a smooth function. Now, I define $V = G - Y^2$, can I say that $V_{|Y=a}$ is Gaussian? and if yes, what are its parameters?

Thanks.

Comment: What you tried?

Comment: If $G$ was independent of $Y$, then the problem is easy. The dependence between the two random variables confuses me. Could this dependence have an effect on the distribution of $G$ and eventually that of $V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: suppose $Y=\sqrt{(X-W)_+}$, $W$ and $X$ are independent and $f(W,Y)=W$. Here, $t_+$ denotes truncation at zero. Then $X$ and $Z$ are independent, but
$$
V=(X-W)-(X-W)_+.
$$
Obviously, $V|Y=a$ is not Gaussian. My example is not very elegant but you could make up examples of your own.